# In HTML is it possible to create asynchronous request without Ajax and/or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I woulk like to know if with HTML is it possible to create asynchronous request without Ajax and/or JavaScript? I don't know if other methods exists to avoid full page reloads?

Comment: You mean using only the markup language itself? I don't think it's possible, you need some level of scripting to do that.

Comment: could you explain further? I can't clearly see an immediate correlation between page reloads and asynchrnous requests. Why js wouldn't be a choice? Please take some time to better elaborate your problem

Comment: @F. Calderan Do you know another methods than asynchrnous requests to avoid page reloads (in HTML) ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you want to load a part of the page, you could use an `iframe`.

Comment: I'm just looking for other solutions like Ajax but not Ajax. Somethink that allow me to load HTML, XML or text, data or other part of code without reloading a full page. That is so hard to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To communicate with the server in any way, no I'm afraid you need Javascript

Answer (score 1):

Iframes allow you to do that.

```
<a href="foo" target="iframe_name">linky</a>
```

See [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.5)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid full page reload, you can have frames or iframes and links targeting those (i)frames.

```
<a href=somehref target=myiframe>my link</a>
<iframe name=myiframe></iframe>
```

But you'll be fast limited if you don't use javascript at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can somehow simulate AJAX behavior using `<frame>` ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/frame)) and `<iframe>` ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/HTML/Element/iframe)).

You can then specify the `target` attribute of `<a>` links to result in a request within the (i)frame with the respective ID ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/a)).

This technique, however, is more or less abandoned in favor of using the usual JavaScript AJAX requests.